# How to download non-shared file without access_token in query via the Google Drive API as of January 2020

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

**Situation**

I'm currently using the Google Drive API to list files and allow users to download those files. The files are *not* shared and the download option is *disabled* (`copyRequiresWriterPermission = true`)

To do so, I currently execute a CURL call to `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{file_id}?access_token={access_token}&alt=media` on the server side and redirect the user to the `Location` header value of the response which will look something like `{....}-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/drive/v3/files/{file_id}?qk={....}`.

**Problem**

However, the usage of the `access_token` query in files.get or files.export will not be longer possible as of January 1, 2020 ([Announcement: Upcoming changes to the Google Drive API and Google Picker API](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api)).

Changing the request to authenticate via the HTTP header (`Authorization: Bearer {accces_token}`) will not work in this situation as it will start the download immediately on the server side and I can't redirect the user to a temporarily download URL. Redirecting the user to the `webContentLink` will not work as it requires the file to be publicly shared.

Other cloud services like Dropbox/OneDrive/Box do offer the creation of a temporarily download url via their API but that doesn't seem to be the case for the Google Drive API.

**Question**

So I am wondering, how do I download files via the Google Drive API as of January 1, 2020 keeping the following requirements:

- The file need to be downloaded on the client side via the browser and not on the server side
- The access token cannot be shared with the client side
- The file will not have any sharing permissions set

Does anyone have any clues how to proceed?

Comment: Can I ask you about the file size and mimeType you want to download?

Comment: The same as currently is possible: all sizes and all files types (except Google Docs).

Comment: Thank you for replying. If the size is less than 50 MB, the file can be downloaded by Web Apps, and I had tried to propose this. But in your situation, it was found that this cannot be used. So in order to think of other workaround, I have a question. In your question, you say `The file will not have any sharing permissions set`. In this case, can the file be temporarily shared? For example, it's 1 minute.

Comment: Not really. If a specific file is downloaded (e.g.) every 2 minutes it will mean that the file is public 50% of the time. Unfortunately, changing the sharing permission, download the file and reverting the permission isn't really an option. Nevertheless, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my proposal was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this and I have to study more and more.

Comment: There's a section on the documentation announcing the deprecation (the one you shared) that includes an alternative to working with HTTP headers. Also, is it possible to do a normal `files.get` for you? If that's the case, then you can use `downloadUrl` or `exportLinks` file properties ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files)) and provide them to the client directly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, I can't use the HTTP headers on the client side as it will reveal the access token. Besides that, the downloadUrl (v2 API only) and exportLinks only work when the file is shared. When the file doesn't have public sharing permissions, you will have to login before you can access the files via those urls.